# Global symbol in static libstdc++.a is local in shared libstdc++.so

Tags: c++, linker, g++, libstdc++

While trying to use `__gcclibcxx_demangle_callback` as a non-allocating alternative to `__cxa_demangle`, I'm hitting an issue that is giving me some trouble.  When I link against `libstdc++` statically, the symbol is located, but when I link dynamically, g++ reports:

```
undefined reference to `__gcclibcxx_demangle_callback'
```

Curiously, `nm` lists it in one but not the other:

```
me@compy:/lib$ nm libstdc++.a | grep demangle
0000543d T __cxa_demangle
0000550d T __gcclibcxx_demangle_callback
me@compy:/lib$ nm -D libstdc++.so | grep demangle
0004eabd T __cxa_demangle
```

The output of readelf gives a hint as to why - it's global in the static, and local in the shared:

```
me@compy:/lib$ readelf -s libstdc++.a | grep demangle
   179: 0000543d   208 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 __cxa_demangle
   180: 0000550d    32 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 __gcclibcxx_demangle_callback
me@compy:/lib$ readelf -s libstdc++.so | grep demangle
  8313: 0004eb8d    32 FUNC    LOCAL  DEFAULT   12 __gcclibcxx_demangle_callback
 10871: 0004eabd   208 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   12 __cxa_demangle
```

Linking my entire application against `libstdc++` statically is not an option.

My question is twofold:

1. Why is the visibility different between the two?
2. How can I gain access to this symbol?  Is there a way to get at it dynamically, or to link statically only against the object file where this symbol resides?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly,the visibility is different because, of the two, only `__cxa_demangle` gets declared in the `<cxxabi.h>` header. That header contains a `#pragma GCC visibility push(default)` which ensures all declarations in it are made visible when compiling with `-fvisibility=hidden`.

Secondly, you could link statically to libstdc++ or alternatively link to libiberty. libiberty exports `cplus_demangle_v3_callback` which uses the same underlying function as `__gcclibcxx_demangle_callback`. It just doesn't have any parameter checking and doesn't select required demangling options. You can call it like this:

```
template <typename F>
struct lambda_caller
{
    F f;
    constexpr lambda_caller(F f) : f(std::move(f)) {}
    static void call(const char* data, size_t length, void* self)
    {
        static_cast<lambda_caller*>(self)->f(data, length);
    }
};

if (!lambda_caller callback{[&](const char* data, size_t length) {
        ::write(STDERR_FILENO, data, length);
    }}; ::cplus_demangle_v3_callback(mangled_name, DMGL_PARAMS | DMGL_TYPES,
                                   &callback::call, &callback))
    throw std::invalid_argument
        "mangled_name is not validly mangled according to C++ ABI rules"};
```